# c# large number suffix

Tags: c#, formatting

I am searching for a library or a way to create extremely large numbers as suffixes like this - https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/erosson/number-suffix/1.1.0/NumberSuffix#suffixAlphabetic but for c#. Can someone point me what should i look for, because I didn't find anything like this for c#.

```
format config 1e3 --> "1,000"
format config 1e5 --> "100K"
format config 1e6 --> "1.00M"
format config 1e9 --> "1.00B"
format config 1e12 --> "1.00T"
format config 1e15 --> "1.00aa"
format config 1e18 --> "1.00ab"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


namespace ConsoleApplication163
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SuffixAlphabetic[] numbers = { 
                   new SuffixAlphabetic() {number = 1000, format = "1e3"},
                   new SuffixAlphabetic() {number = 100000, format = "1e5"},
                   new SuffixAlphabetic() {number = 1000000, format = "1e6"},
                   new SuffixAlphabetic() {number = 1000000000, format = "1e9"},
                   new SuffixAlphabetic() {number = 1000000000000, format = "1e12"},
                    new SuffixAlphabetic() {number = 1000000000000000, format = "1e15"},
                    new SuffixAlphabetic() {number = 1000000000000000000, format = "1e18"}
                                         };

            foreach (SuffixAlphabetic number in numbers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(SuffixAlphabetic.ToString(number));
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    public class SuffixAlphabetic
    {
        static string[] standardSuffix = { "", "K", "M", "B", "T" };
        public long number { get; set; }
        public string format { get; set; }
        public static string ToString(SuffixAlphabetic number)
        {
            double temp = 0;
            int exp = int.Parse(number.format.Replace("1e", ""));
            int thousand = exp / 3;

            string results = "";

            if (thousand <= 1)
            {
                return String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:0,0}", number.number);  
            }

            temp = number.number / Math.Pow(10, exp);
            results = String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:#,##0.00}", temp);
            if (thousand <= 4)
            {
                results += standardSuffix[thousand];
                return results;
            }
            else
            {
                char letter = (char)((thousand - 5) + ((byte)'a'));
                results += "a" + letter;
                return results;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, It does output exactly what is shown in my question. But i guess it is limited to a certain number because if i want to output something like 1.00zz it won't work with the current type, any idea how this can be extended to work with even larger numbers ? Even using bigint wont be enough. Is there a way to conver a extremely large number without using specific types ?

Comment: .At work a long time ago one of our scientist build an Exponentiator where he did math using arrays of bytes.  He was doing research on generating large prime numbers.